# MySQL add to the contents of a column in an UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update, insert-update

Im not sure if this is possible and I'm not finding documentation on it so I thought I would ask the experts.

Is there a way in a MySQL query to add to the existing contents of a column. For example say I have the following table:

**table**

```
id     name     value
1      Bob      red
```

I would like to use a query to add more to the `value` column while preserving the value that is already there. So for example:

```
UPDATE `yable` SET `value` += ',blue' WHERE `id` = 1;
```

Would update the row to the following:

**table**

```
id     name     value
1      Bob      red,blue
```

Is this possible or do I need to use a different language (like PHP) to concatenate the string before updating?

Comment: `CONCAT(value,',blue')` is available to you... But I would _strongly_ advise against comma separated values in 1 fields, go for normalization if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE `yable` SET `value`= `value` + ',blue' WHERE `id` = 1;
```

is another way to write it.

```
+=
```

is a short way to write that.

also you got function `CONCAT()`

```
UPDATE `yable` SET `value`= CONCAT(value,',blue') WHERE `id` = 1;
```